# What can damage tanks in Hell Let Loose?

Tags: hell-let-loose

In *Hell Let Loose* tanks are quite a menace and you pretty much need your own tank or an Anti-Tank soldier to deal with it. However, there are various other weapons that could harm the tank: normal grenades, artillery I suppose, mines, normal fire?, etc.

So, what weapons can damage a tank in *Hell Let Loose*?